# Rank-enum for use in different card games.

Tags: java, enums, interface

I'm implementing a generic Deck that should be able to support different card-games.

I have interfaces for Deck and Card, An enums for Suit and Rank.

My question is about Rank. In blackjack for instance, you have the values 2-10. Picture-cards are 10, and Ace is either 1 or 11.

While in poker this is not the case anymore and so on.

With those examples in mind - Is enum the best approach? Right now it looks like this:

```
public enum Rank {
    TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10),
    JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13), ACE(14);

    private final int value;

    public Rank(int value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Or should Rank just be an interface, so the values can be correctly assigned by the person implementing it?

Comment: This feels more like a usability question - there are various other forums on stackexchange that may be better suited for this question.

Comment: The way ranking works depends on the Game. Do you have a Game interface? If so, why not create a generic IRank<T>, and have this Rank implementation be a Rank implements IRank<GameImpl>? If you have more than one game that uses the same Ranking you could have another layer of abstraction for that.

Comment: Ask yourself the fundamental modeling questions. Is the card's rank name, i.e., `ACE`, `DEUCE`, `TREY`, ..., `KING`, inherent? Are there a fixed number of ranks? Yes and yes, so an enum is appropriate. Is the value assigned to each rank inherent to the rank? No, of course not. It's assigned by the game rules. So does the value belong as a field of `Rank`? Of course not.

Comment: @LewBloch I ended up making both rank and suit as interfaces, and implemented them in the Game class so I can easily override them depending on the current card game.